# How to adjust URLs in the reference while using two column format?

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, urls

I have written an article in two columns format and used bibtex to make the list of references. I needed to use the Harvard style. The URLs got all messed up. How can I fix this?
I saw some posts advising to break URLs where it has any hyphens. But almost all the URLs I have, don't have hyphens in them. Few had hyphens and those were automatically adjusted.
Editing to add a MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{example,
title = {Predicting the need for ICU admission in community-acquired pneumonia},
journal = {Respiratory Medicine},
volume = {155},
pages = {61-65},
year = {2019},
issn = {0954-6111},
doi = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.rmed.2019.07.007},
url = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0954611119302331},
author = {Alessandra Morello Gearhart and Stephen Furmanek and Connor English and Julio Ramirez and Rodrigo Cavallazzi}
}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite{example}

\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As usual on this site your chances of getting an answer will greatly increase if you provide a MWE.

Comment: @campa what MWE should I provide for this? An entry from the bibtex file?

Comment: Well, at the very least the `\documentclass`, the bibliography-related packages (e.g. `natbib`) and one entry to play with. Please have a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4408/82917.

Comment: if bibtex is generating these links, odds are that it uses the `\url` command try loading the `url` or `xurl` packags which adjusts `\url` to provide better line breaks

Comment: Please edit your posting to show a couple of bib entries that contain long URL strings. Please also state which bibliography style you employ.

Comment: Edited my question to add an MWE. And I did try to add URL and xurl packages, nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `natbib` package is aware of the Harvard family and defines

```
\newcommand\harvardurl[1]{\textbf{URL:} \textit{#1}}
```

which of course messes up the job done by the package `url` (and also `hyperref`, since it does not create a link). You should then redefine this macro to properly use `\url`. I would also type the bibliography ragged right, otherwise you are bound to get a lot of underfull `\hbox`es in a two-column layout.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{example,
title = {Predicting the need for ICU admission in community-acquired pneumonia},
journal = {Respiratory Medicine},
volume = {155},
pages = {61-65},
year = {2019},
issn = {0954-6111},
doi = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.rmed.2019.07.007},
url = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0954611119302331},
author = {Alessandra Morello Gearhart and Stephen Furmanek and Connor English and Julio Ramirez and Rodrigo Cavallazzi}
}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[twocolumn, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\renewcommand\harvardurl[1]{\textbf{URL:} \url{#1}}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Text text \cite{example}.

\begingroup
\raggedright
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked, and also by using \raggedright a few overlaps were eliminated.